# Retrieve remote data source as user types using angular-chosen

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

Is there any way to use this plugin to retrieve data from a remote source as a user types? I've seen the examples in jQuery but nothing for this Angular wrapper. The only alternative is to load a huge array of data upfront-- which isn't ideal.

Comment: can you give us more context, please.

Comment: Sure, here's the documentation:

https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen

At the bottom there's an explanation on how to retrieve data from a remote source; however, there is no documentation nor example on how to dynamically update the data source as the user is utilizing the search box. All examples assume the full data set has already been loaded. This doesn't make sense for large production datasets. Does that make sense?

Comment: Been looking for this too and came accross this. Hope someone can shed some light on this.